# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client node.js MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code inside my function:

```
var postTitle = req.body.postTitle;
var postDescription = req.body.postDescription;
var socialLink = req.body.socialLink;

if (postTitle != undefined || postDescription != undefined || socialLink != undefined) {
    next()
} else {
    return err
}


client.connect().then (() => {
const database = client.db("myFirstDatabase");
const socialPosts = database.collection("socialPosts");

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const doc = { title: postTitle, description: postDescription, socialLink: socialLink };
    socialPosts.insertOne(doc)
    res.redirect("/")
    db.close();
    });
});
```

when I run this, I get this:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I am not sure why I am getting that, becuase I am not trying to render the front-end anywhere else, all the code you see is the entire function.

It's worth noting I am new to MongoDB, so it may be the fact that I am an amateur and could be missing smt so small!

Comment: Your undefined check seems weird; and you're calling next(), but then also `res.redirect()`, which is what causes the error

Comment: @ChrisG spot on, that was weird, not sure y i did that lol. thx

Comment: @ChrisG I dont understand. Won't next() move the flow to the next middleware, preventing the call to res.redirect()?

Comment: @TusharShahi It'll tell express to continue to the next matching request handler, but you still have to exit the current handler function yourself, or it keeps running. express is just JavaScript.